# How To do ReOrdering in Page Block Table rows with inline edit feature as well?

Tags: jquery, pageblocktable, inline-visualforce, inlineeditsupport

I have a requirement where I need to develop a Pageblock table which should be inline editable as well as the user can reorder the table rows like the drag and drop functionality.

This order should be saved in the database so that I can display the records next time in the order where the user had last time left after reordering, when the page is refreshed.
I tried with the Jquery sortable functions but the reordering of the rows (like the drag and drop works) did not work, below is the code mentioned for it :-

```
<apex:page controller="DraggableTableRows_PageBlockTable">

<apex:includeScript value="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"/>
<apex:includeScript value="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.tablesorter/2.18.3/js/jquery.tablesorter.js"/>
<apex:includeScript value="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.tablesorter/2.18.3/js/jquery.tablesorter.widgets.js"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<apex:stylesheet value="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.tablesorter/2.18.3/css/theme.jui.css"/>

<script>
    $j = jQuery.noConflict();

    var fixHelperModified = function(e, tr) {
        var $originals = tr.children();
        var $helper = tr.clone();
        $helper.children().each(function(index) {
            $j(this).width($originals.eq(index).width())
        });
        return $helper;
    };

    var updateIndex = function(e, ui) {
        $j('td.index', ui.item.parent()).each(function (i) {
            $j(this).html(i + 1);
        });
    };

    $j(document).ready(function() {
        $j("#sort tbody > span").sortable({
            helper: fixHelperModified,
            stop: updateIndex
        }).disableSelection();


</script> 

    <apex:form>

        <apex:pageBlock title="My Content">

            <apex:pageBlockTable id="sort" value="{!listOfAccount}" var="item">

                <apex:column styleClass="index" value="{!item.id}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!item.name}"/>

            </apex:pageBlockTable>

        </apex:pageBlock>


    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

---

```
public with sharing class DraggableTableRows_PageBlockTable {

    public list<Account> listOfAccount{get;set;}

    public DraggableTableRows_PageBlockTable(){

        listOfAccount = [select id,name from account limit 10];    

    }

    public String[] getStrings() {
        return new String[]{'ONE','TWO','THREE'};
    }

}
```

How can I achieve this requirement?

Comment: What does "it did not work" mean? Could you please edit your question to include a clear and detailed description of the behavior that you need to change or a specific error message you receive?

Comment: @DavidReed, I have updated the question mentioning what "did not work".